# How to use 'Inject' without decorator in Mobx with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I wonder how to use Inject without decorator.
First, I made this as Store.

```
 //Data/imagedb
import { decorate, observable } from 'mobx';

class imageStore {
  list = {
    keyword : 'yoyo',
  }
}

decorate(imageStore, {
  list: observable,
})

export default imageStore;
```

Second, I made this code to inject Store on it.

```
//components/Image
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

class Image extends Component {
    render() {
        const onPut2 = {onPut};
        return (
            <div>
                {onPut2}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default inject(({ imSt }) => ({
    onPut: imSt.list.keyword,
}))(observer(Image));
```

And finally, this is my last code. 
The error is "Onput is not defined" in second code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'components/Image';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import imageStore from 'Data/imagedb'

const imSt = new imageStore();

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Provider imSt={imSt}>    
                <Image />
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: `const onPut2 = {onPut};` - onPut is actually never defined. as it says... not an issue with mobx.

Comment: Yes. So that codes have my mistake. Could you explain how can solve this problem..

Comment: at a guess, this will come as a prop after you inject it. so `const { onPut } = this.props` to grab it

Comment: It works well!! Thank you so much haha